# Generic parameters for mix-in interfaces

Tags: java, generics

I am experimenting with mixin interfaces that add additional functionality to existing interfaces. E.g. I have an interface Filtering

```
interface Filtering<T, E>{

    T filter(Filter<E> f);

}
```

I can easily add that to existing interfaces:

```
interface Container<E> extends Filter<Container<E>, E>{
    // translated type: Container<E> filter(Filter<E> f);
}
```

Now I'd also like to have a transforming behavior, that transforms `Container<E>` to `Container<X>` with the syntax

```
Container<X> transform(Transformer<E,X> transformer)
```

Is there any way I can define this functionality as a Mix-in interface, so that I can transform `Container<E>` to `Container<X>` but also `SomeOtherContainer<E>` to `SomeOtherContainer<X>`?

```
interface Transforming< /* what goes in here? >{

    < /* and what goes in here? */ > X transform(Transformer<S,T> transformer);
}

interface Container<E> extends Transforming<Container<E>, /* and in here? */ >{
}
```

Personally, I don't think it's possible, I think I need to add the transform method to each of the target interfaces, but I haven't quite lost hope yet. Can anybody help?

**Clarification:** The `Transformer` function converts the individual `E` elements to `X` elements. I do not want `Transformer` to convert from `Container<E>` to `Container<X>`, that would be completely useless.

This is how I'd like to use it:

```
Container<Integer> intVersion = // initialize it
Container<String> hexVersion =
    intVersion.transform(new Transformer<Integer,String>(){
       public String apply(Integer input){
           return Integer.toHexString(input);
       }
});
```

**BTW:** I know I can do similar stuff in Guava. Let's ignore that fact for this question, this is not so much about the functionality (which I can easily implement), but about generics usage.

Comment: I'm confused what Transforming gives you that Transformer doesn't.

Comment: @glowcoder Let's say I want to convert a basket of apples to a basket of oranges. Transformer converts a single apple to a single orange. I'm looking for a way to specify that, given a `Transformer<I,O>`, I can return a basket of any type of fruit

Comment: @Sean so you want to turn `basket = {apple, orange, pear, glowcoder} // yeah I'm a fruit!` and turn them all into `apples` or all into `pears`?

Comment: I am little bit confused but what about generic methods? One generic parameter can be given within the interface and another one is specified for method only. But I am not sure that it is what you want

Comment: A problem I would see is that you would need some kind of registry that allows you to get the Transformer for a given object. Perhaps `getTransformer(X destinationType)` needs to go into your `Transformable` interface

Comment: @glowcoder no I want to turn a basket of apples into a basket of pears and a bag of apples into a bag of pears (both of these would use the same transformer object that can transform a single apple to a single pear).

Comment: @glowcoder no that would make things much to complicated. Before I do that, I'll rather add a transform() method to all interfaces instead of using the mixin version

Comment: @Sean agreed that your comment two above this makes my comment above *it* an obviously poor decision. In that case, I would simply remove the `Transforming` interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, Java doesn't allow this:

```
interface Transforming<E, X>
    <T> X<T> transform(Transformer<E,T> transformer);

interface Container<E> extends Transforming<E, Container>
```

Even if it did, it's not general enough; we want a function mapping `T` to another type containing `T`

```
interface Transforming<E, f>
    <T> f(T) transform(Transformer<E,T> transformer);

interface Container<E> extends Transforming<E, {T->Container<T>} >
```

But enough of fantasies. The best you can do, is to be very vague on return type:

```
interface Transforming<E>
    <X,T> X transform(Transformer<E,T> transformer);

interface Container<E> extends Transforming<E>
```

Note, we are unable to express any constraint between X and T.

Now your sample code compiles, without any warning!! There is a type inference based on the assignment, and `X` is infered to be `Container<String>`.

On one hand, the type safety of this inference entirely depends on programmer supplying the correct target type. If he had put `Container<Rope>` on the left hand, it will compile too without warning.

On the other hand, if Java does not do such inference, then we must return `Object` instead of `X`, and do manual cast on return object; the safety of the manual cast of course also depends entirely on programmer supplying correct target type. Some people therefore argue, why are we punishing ourselves? If I assign A to B, of course A is a B, don't force me to write it out, infer it!

Nonetheless, such inference may give false sense of security to casual observers. There **is** a manual cast, in spirit, but not in writting. Personally I'm quite concerned with this inference rule. It is against the very point of static typing, that is, we *want* to write down all the types explicitly.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was afraid (and almost certain) of, but I had to ask anyway. It means that I will have to clutter several interfaces with `transform()` methods with different return values, instead of mixing in `Transforming`. Thanks for your time.

Comment: so you don't like the `X` return type?

Answer (score 0):

You could try (I'm not completely confident in the syntax, but I think it's close):

```
interface Transforming<X> {
    <Y> Y transform(Transformer<X, Y> transformer);
}

interface Container<E> extends Transforming<Container<E>> {
}
```

Then your Container will have the Transforming functionality. The type Y will be determined at the actual call to transform, based on what Y is for the Transformer object passes to transform.

This will not guarentee the Y is necessarily a Container type, but maybe something in Transformer can give that restriction.

Comment: This is obvious, yes. But it's also totally useless, as it doesn't let me reuse `Transformer` objects for different `Transforming` implementations. `Transformer` should operate on `E`, not on `Container<E>`

Comment: If you want to restrict `Y` use `<Y extends Container<?>>`. Not sure what to use for the `?` though.

Comment: @Willi exactly. I would like the transform method to be compile-time safe, so the return value for `Container<E>.transform(Transformer<E,X>)` would be `Container<X>`. Returning `Container<?>`is not a problem, but also not desirable.

Comment: As far as using the same Transformer object for multiple Transforming implementations, this simply doesn't make sense. It's always possible to make more Transforming classes, each requiring its own specific conversion from/to every other implementation. It's impossible to 100% ensure that the Transformer can know about each and every implementation.

Comment: So, what about `<Y extends Container<X>> Y transform(Transformer<X,Y> transformer)`? Would that solve your problem? Beware, I havn´t tested this.

Comment: @Ken I disagree, this makes perfect sense. Converting a) a Basket of Apples to a Basket of Oranges and b) a Bag of Apples to a bag of Oranges is a scenario where it makes sense for both Basket and Bag to use the same routine to convert a single Apple to a single Orange and just add the mechanism that builds the surrounding container.

Comment: @jmg no, because I don't have a root interface. I'd like to be able to inject this into arbitrary interfaces without there being any hierarchy between them. And btw, you misunderstood me, it would have to be `<Y extends Container<Z>> Y transform(Transformer<E,Z> transformer)`

Comment: @Sean Then, I am afraid it is not possible to do what you want in Java. Real mixins are not possible with Java.

Comment: @jmg you misunderstood me again, I think. I am not looking for a real mixin in the sense that the methods are already implemented. I'd know how to do that with AspectJ if I was desperate enough. I have several interfaces that I want to tag as transforming without cluttering the individual interfaces, the implementation class will also have to implement the mixin interface, obviously.